# SSRS 'Like' Expression comparing two fields

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

How do I write an SSRS LIKE expression to see if one field contains values in another field?  For example if the name in one field is 'Johnson' the name in the second field should also be 'Johnson' and if not then conditional format the color of the field.

Here's code that I have tried so far, which isn't working correctly.

```
=iif(instr(Fields!JT_Name.Value, "Fields!Base_Name.Value"),"Transparent","Yellow")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**INSTR()** function returns an integer specifying the start position of the first occurence of the string.

It returns 0 if the string is not contained.

Try:

```
=iif(instr(Fields!JT_Name.Value, Fields!Base_Name.Value)=0,"Transparent","Yellow")
```

Or if you want to apply the yellow color when the string is not contained try:

```
=iif(instr(Fields!JT_Name.Value, Fields!Base_Name.Value)>0,"Transparent","Yellow")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: When I use the code =0, then nothing is highlighted in yellow even though it should be.  When I use the code >0, then everything is highlighted in yellow even though it shouldn't be.  Is there another way?

Comment: @BIReportGuy, In your expression you surrounded with double quotes the Base Field it could be causing this behaviour. I've updated the expression, give it a try.

Comment: I removed the double quotes and it worked!  Thanks a ton!